# repeat parent group value in ssrs drilldown report

Tags: reporting-services, drilldown

First time poster so please bear with me.  I like to think my question is simple but I can't find an answer anywhere.  So i've created a drilldown report in visual studio 2005 using reporting services (SSRS) and I just want the parent group value to repeat after drilldown.  This is the actual link to the report....

https://dlsgateway.dor.state.ma.us/DLSReports/DLSReportViewer.aspx?ReportName=act_v_est_Receipts&ReportTitle=actual%20vs%20estimated

If you run it, and expand the data for abington, the value 'Abington' only appears once.  I'd like it to repeat in the first column.

Is this possible??

Thanks, 
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very much possible. Just below the text box for the value of **Abington**, select the field that has the values of **Abington**, **Acton** etc